# location setting of images after a new image response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, servlets

I have to make a webpage where needs to display images after every 1 hour dynamically. I have added 1 image using jquery,JavaScript and a servlet.

I want to add another image and change the position of previous image to +1.how to do it?
    
    
    
    
    function Onload(){

```
    $.get("ImageContent4", function(data) {

    document.getElementById("image1").src=data;
    //document.getElementById("image2").src=data;
    });
}
window.onload=Onload();
</script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#4a7d49">
<center>
<h2 style=background-color:red>India Meteorological Department</h2>
</center>

<img id="image1" src=" " style="width:128px ; height:228px";>
</body>
</html>
```

here ImageContent4 is a servlet which is sending an image as a response after page load.

Comment: please provide some code to tell us what have you tried so far and having diifficult with

Comment: Please show us your code you have done so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply replace the 'src' attribute of the image. Using jQuery ...

```
$(function() {
    $("img").attr("src", <put the new url here>);
});
```

You may wish to preload the image before you swap the source, but that's a different question.